# Change DPI setting for Citrix Receiver

Tags: citrix, hdpi

How can I change the screen DPI setting for a Citrix Receiver session on Ubuntu 16.04?

I have a Dell XPS 13 laptop with a very high resolution of 277 dpi:

```
$ xrandr | grep -w connected
eDP1 connected 3200x1800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
```

Under Ubuntu 16.04 I can set the scaling factor to 2 which scales most of the linux applications properly.

When I launch Citrix Receiver 13.3.0 to run a Windows 7 session, everything is displayed too small - obviously the Citrix Receiver does not receive the scaling information set in Unity.

These are the dpi settings that I could read out so far:

```
$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep DPI
[5.696] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96,96)

$ xdpyinfo | grep dots
resolution: 96x96 dots per inch

$ xrdb -query | grep dpi
Xft.dpi: 192
```

I tried changing lightdm.conf as mentioned in some articles, but it did not change anything.

Comment: There is a workaround using the scale factor option in [VirtualBox]( https://plutonsblog.wordpress.com/2017/01/22/citrix-receiver-on-a-4k-hidpi-laptop/) but I didn't find any other solution for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It is again a workaround, but a lighter one than the one mentioned in the comment: you can install vncserver, start an additional lightweight X session (openbox or similar) and run icaclient there.

There are vncclients which can do clipboard sync so the experience is really seamless, and you don't need to run a full virtual machine.

(I can even imagine putting icaclient to your ~/.vnc/xstartup without any window manager for a super light experience.)

Answer (score 0):

Version 2207 of the citrix workspace app introduces [technical preview support for DPI matching](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-workspace-app-for-linux/configure-xenapp.html#support-for-dpi-matching-technical-preview) which seems to work.