# How do I increase the font size for a specific application in Ubuntu 18.04 running Gnome?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, fonts, display-resolution

I installed the Unity Editor on my Thinkpad x1 Carbon, which has a resolution of `2560 x 1440`, and is considered HiDPI. In order to deal with very small font sizes, I installed `gnome-tweak-tools` and set my `Fonts` `Scaling Factor` to `1.34`. This has resulted in an acceptable font size in every application I have tried so far, with some tweaks in programs like Firefox.

However, the Unity Editor doesn't have a font size modifier for its UI. It looks like this on my machine:

[image: Screenshot of Unity Editor on a Thinkpad x1 Carbon running Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome]

The font size is unreadably small.

I see that under `gnome-tweak-tools`, I can set font sizes specifically for things such as "Window Title" or "Document," but not, for example, "Unity Editor."

I could set "Scaling Factor" very high but this makes other programs have unacceptably large fonts.

I could modify, under the regular `Settings` app, under `Displays`, the `Scale` property, from `100%` to `200%`, but this makes every other application have a terribly bloated, nearly unusably large UI.

**How can I change the font size for only one application**, specifically, Unity Editor?

EDIT: By the way, there does not appear to be any intention on the Unity Editor engineering team to implement a font size changer: https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-change-font-size-in-unity-editor.149481/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a script call `ue` (Unity Editor). Place within it:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
xrandr --dpi 144
unity-editor "$@"    # Or whatever the program is you want to run
```

Mark the script as executable using:

```bash
chmod a+x ue
```

Call the script using

```bash
./ue
```

- Or replace `./` with the directory name if not in the current directory
- Or leave off `./` if you have placed `ue` in your `$PATH` like `~/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`

Adjust 144 to 192 if you want it double magnification. Smaller if you want less magnification.

Your screen may blink when script starts up but that is normal.

---

**TL;DR**

The default **DPI** (**D**ots **P**er **I**nch) is 96. When set to `100` font size increased by 4% which might not be noticeable. To confirm initial DPI use one of these commands:

```bash
$ xdpyinfo | grep dots
  resolution:    96x96 dots per inch

$ grep DPI /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[     9.555] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (43, 44); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[     9.761] (==) modeset(G0): DPI set to (96, 96)
```

In the above script you can reset `xrandr` back to default DPI of `96` by adding the following line to the bottom:

```bash
xrandr --dpi 96
```

I've never encountered a need to do this, but you might.

Comment: You may also want to indicate how the magnification can be reset after the application is closed.

Comment: @vanadium I've done this plus given an overview of DPI in general.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is awesome. Apologies for not accepting yet - still out of town and waiting to get home on Monday to test.

Comment: For me, on Gnome Shell with Xorg (Ubuntu 19.04) this does not seem to work. I have tested with the command  "xrandr --dpi 144 ; leafpad", and leafpad starts as usual, without any change in resolution.

Comment: @vanadium I only used leafpad once on lubuntu 16.04 inside virtual box and to change font size I probably did something different. For myself I use `--dpi 144` with `kid3` if you have `kid3` installed you can try that.

Comment: This is not about leafpad: I only used it to test. On Gnome shell, the xrand --dpi command apparently has no effect. The --scale option does, however.

Comment: @vanadium `xrandr --dpi 144` has no effect on normal applications. It only works on applications that are not hdpi aware and use default system font with no ability to override font size. Try testing on `kid3`. It should work on all Ubuntu versions using `xorg`. I've never had to use `--scale` but I was under the impression it scales the entire monitor which OP doesn't want.

Comment: Strange. a.f.a.i.k., xrandr changes the entire screen, independently of a single application. What is your desktop environment?

Comment: @vanadium I assume you still haven't tested `kid3` yet? I'm on 16.04 but `xrandr --dpi 144` also worked in 14.04. I can reboot and test `kid3` in 18.04 if you like. BTW google-earth is another application where I use `xrandr --dpi 196`

Comment: 16.04 and the Unity desktop? For me, the -dpi option does not work in the Gnome Desktop (19.04).

Comment: @vanadium But what application are you using in GDM 19.04? As I said applications that are already hdpi aware ignore dpi in xrandr.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix For sure you are right, this works for kid3!

Comment: @vanadium haha you probably thought I was kidding :) On a serious note it's been a problem in google-earth too since 2011 and I just posted an answer using --dpi there: https://askubuntu.com/questions/41562/how-to-fix-fonts-in-google-earth-6

Comment: @vanadium I answered this bounty and afterwards noticed you issued it?: https://askubuntu.com/questions/808141/change-dpi-setting-for-citrix-receiver/1158294#1158294

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, the other question is specific to Citrix receiver. Inspired by your answer I attempted to also increase appearance of citrix clients, but without succes. A more specific approach will be needed.

Comment: Thanks !! I had this issue with Arduino IDE menu font size. It's fixed !

Answer (score 1):

The following does not change only the font, but scales the entire interface:

```
 QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.34 application
```

Possibly, one may also want to play around with the above in combination with `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1` and `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0`.

I hope hope it can be useful, though it is not exactly what you seek.