# Citrix Resolution on Linux Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: display-resolution, citrix

The resolution of my PC is 3200x1800 but I have enabled 2x scaling on my Windows and Linux machines.

When I connect using Workspace app from my Windows machine then the resolution of my remote PC is appropriately set to 1600 x 900. But when I connect from my Ubuntu machine then the resolution of remote PC stays at 3200x1800 and as a result I see very small text.

What do I need to do to ensure that my remote PC is scaled properly?

I am running the latest packages "Citrix Workspace app for Linux (x86_64)", downloaded from:
https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/linux/workspace-app-for-linux-latest.html

Comment: I believe there is no direct solution to this problem with the linux citrix client. The only workaround I found was to install Citrix in a Virtual Box virtual machine and then use the autoscaling option of virtual box.

Comment: The question [was ask here too "Change DPI setting for Citrix Receiver"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/808141/change-dpi-setting-for-citrix-receiver) and lead to the same kind of workaround I suggested: VirtualBox or using VNC (but I didn't try the later). A bug report should be send to Citrix in this subject.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I have found is to use Google Chrome and install the Citrix Workspace Chrome App. DPI scaling is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. Turns out the problem comes from fractional scaling setting in "Display Settings". So simply turning off "Fractional Scaling" fixed the issue for me

Instructions on how to enable/disable "Fractional Scaling" can be found [here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/04/ubuntu-20-04-fractional-scaling-support-setting)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `DPIMatchingEnabled=True` in your `$HOME/.ICAClient/All\_Regions.ini` file

This worked for me when I had the same problem (although I am using Ubuntu 22.04)